# How to Use Microsoft Graph in a Multi-Tenant environment?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an ASP.NET web application which has multitenancy supported in it . I have a requirement to integrate microsoft graph to access and write to outlook calendars.My question is , will every Tenant have its own application id and secret key ?  Or will one secret key and application Id be common to all tenants ? Please provide me details of what needs to be changed as this is somehow misleading and vague.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try like this for multi-tenant apps `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in the docs under Step 4 of [Register an application with the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0):

> - **Supported account types** - Select which accounts you would like your application to support.
>
>   - **Accounts in this organizational directory only** - Select this option if you're building a line-of-business (LOB) application. This option is not available if you're not registering the application in a directory.
>
>     This option maps to Azure AD only single-tenant.
>
>     This is the default option unless you're registering the app outside of a directory. In cases where the app is registered outside of a directory, the default is Azure AD multi-tenant and personal Microsoft accounts.
>   - **Accounts in any organizational directory** - Select this option if you would like to target all business and educational customers.
>
>     This option maps to an Azure AD only multi-tenant.
>
>     If you registered the app as Azure AD only single-tenant, you can update it to be Azure AD multi-tenant and back to single-tenant through the Authentication blade.
>   - **Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts** - Select this option to target the widest set of customers.
>
>     This option maps to Azure AD multi-tenant and personal Microsoft accounts.
>
>     If you registered the app as Azure AD multi-tenant and personal Microsoft accounts, you cannot change this in the UI. Instead, you must use the application manifest editor to change the supported account types.

Comment: hey @Marc LaFleur , Thanks for your valuable contribution.In another note, let us say my main sign in mechanism is independent of Microsoft;Accordingly, should I opt for implementing a login button and store encrypted versions of access tokens in my database or is there another way ?

Comment: I assume you're asking about what many apps refer to collocliolly as "connecting" or "linking" an external account? This is done by authenticating the user using the Authorization Code grant and including `offline_access` in your requested scopes. This will return a Refresh Token that you can store and use to obtain a new Access Token ondemand. Refresh Tokens don't have a lifetime but they can be invalidated so you may want to validate  their still good at login.